# Getting connection with QBFC C# with company files another machine

Tags: c#, quickbooks, qbfc

I am using Visual Studio on Machine A which does not have Quickbooks. I want to try to access the company datafiles which are on machine B using QBFC (at least if I can). I just need a simple example of making the connection, the rest I can work out. I can't even open a session. I have used nuget to get the lastest QBFC13. A simple open/close would be very helpful.

```
sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("CA", 13, 0);
requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;            
sessionManager.OpenConnection2(@"\\\IP_address\CurrentFile\Myfile.QBW", 
    "QuickBooks Integration Demo", ENConnectionType.ctRemoteQBD);
connectionOpen = true;
sessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
sessionBegun = true;
IItemQuery itemQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendItemQueryRq();    
IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
IResponse response = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0);
IORItemRetList itemRetList = (IORItemRetList)response.Detail;
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Hi Rufus, here is the error message: Exeption in OpenConnection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: You need to have Quickbooks installed on the machine you want to open it on.